# How to avoid html class change?

Tags: html, css, streamlit

I am building a streamlit app which has four pages. The last page is where data is being visualized through filters using st.multiselect(). Now the issue is the 'clear all' which appears as 'X' in the individual multiselect is overlapping the delete option of the element which also appears as 'X'. Now when trying to hide the 'clear all' using css styling, I am able to get the class name using the 'inspect' element of html and applying it does hide the clear all 'X'. But after the page is refreshed, the class name changes and the 'x' re appears.
The class name of clear all looks like this: <svg data-baseweb="icon" title='Clear all" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Clear all" role="button" class="st-d4 st-d5 st-du st-dv st-dw st-dx st-dy"> ==$0
One of the component in class is changing dynamically. I want to keep the clear all 'X' hidden so that the 'delete' option of the filter element is visible

Comment: you need a way to distinguish those elements from the others in a strict way. The `<svg>` element you showed doesn't hold any that could be used to craft a good criteria. So far I can only see the attribute `title` but it wouldn't be safe nor elegant. Can you add a class to the element like `delete-btn`? so that a simple css selector like `.delete-btn` would be enough

Comment: otherwise the dirty trick would be something like `*[title="Clear all"]{display: none;}`

Comment: so will only this much work [title="Clear all"]{display: none;} ?

Comment: I don’t know why you ask again something expecting to have a different answer. Really? Really Really?